# PagerAdapter prevent destroying already loaded views

Tags: android, performance, caching, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to prevent my `ViewPager`'s PagerAdapter from destroying Views it already loaded once.

If I understood it correctly, the method `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` will create and cache a page on each side of the selected view.

This is okay for me, except for the part that if I for example jump to page 5, pages 4 and 5 will be created and cached, but pages 0 and 1 will be destroyed.

I've tried commenting out everything in my pager's `destroyItem()` method, and caching in a `HashMap` the views created in `instantiateItem()`, and returning them as-is if they are found on the `HashMap`.

This seems to be working OK, but I'm not sure if there are any downsides to doing that this way, apart from the higher memory usage, which is hopefully not a problem here.

My app is actually an application framework and I'm going to leave that decision to the final developer, leaving `ViewPager`'s default behavior in case he/she doesn't want to apply this caching behaviour. Some clients are pretty unreasonable and they have a huge number of views in everypage. I've tried to convince them to work their way around in different pages since Android's View creation is costly, but as I said, they're unreasonable.

Do you guys know of any good way to do this?

Comment: maybe `recyclerview`+`viewpager` ? there 's a github project  [link](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager)

Comment: @SarantisTofas Not really, I want it to create the views as I move around the ViewPager. If setOffscreenPageLimit is set to the total of possible pages, all of them will be created at once, slowing down the creation of the Activity.

Comment: @Reaper yes you are right, i am deleting my comment since it provides no help